# Vuejs how to pass data prop from jquery

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am using Laravel, vue and js in my project

I wanted to get the data passed in my class `vueAddReview` from

```
<div id="app-vue">
    <add-review class="vueAddReview"></add-review>
</div>
```

I am setting a data in the `vueAddReview` class by using jQuery

```
    $(document).on('click', '.writeReview', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var addReviewModal = $('.addReviewModal');
    addReviewModal.modal('show');

    var listingId = $('.writeReview').data('listing-id');

    $('.vueAddReview').data('listing-id', listingId);
});
```

My problem here is I don't know how to pass `$('.vueAddReview').data('listing-id')` into vue as a prop

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it work, you can initialize data in your root Vue component ( here, `app-vue` ) and pass it as a props

```
const app-vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app-vue',
    data: () => {
        foobar: $('.vueAddReview').data('listing-id')
    }
});
```

And then you can pass it as a props to his child component

```
<add-review :listing-id="foobar"></add-review>
```

( IMHO it is a bit awkward to init a Vue component with a DOM element data. The DOM should not be a source of truth for your model. Is there a way for you to not use a jQuery attribute to init your Vue Component ? )